# Angular2/4: What do [] and () means in angular html files?

Tags: angular

I'm having trouble understanding this. What does the following line mean?

```
<virtual-scroll [items]="items" (update)="viewPortItems = $event">
```

1) What do the [] brackets means?

2) Why is there a '=' after the [] brackets? What are we assigning to?

3) What about the () brackets? Is it a function?

4) MOST CONFUSING PART: Why is there an '=' sign next to "viewPortItems".. and then there is an '$event' sign which is an observable I presume. What's going on here?

Comment: First page of documentation on angular website...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need learn the basics of Angular 2 in order to understand these concepts.

1. The `[items]="items"` is data binding in Angular 2 to pass data from parent component to `virtual-scroll` component where `"items"` is the property in parent component and `[items]` is the property of child component viz. `virtual-scroll`.
2. The `=` passes the data from parent component to child component.
3. `(update)="viewPortItems = $event"` is an event handler to the `update` event from `virtual-scroll` component. `"viewPortItems = $event"` assigns the event object to the `viewPortItems` property in parent component.

I hope this helps :)